# How do we show sum of independent variables are independent?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have four random variables $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},X_{4}$, we know they are independent. Now we want to prove $X_{1}+X_{2}$ and $X_{3}+X_{4}$ are independent.

Could someone help me with it?

Comment: How did you prove that $X_1+X_2,X_3,X_4$ are pairwise independent? Why are you unable to repeat/twist that argument?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I just found my argument is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb P\{X_1+X_2\leq x, X_3+X_4\leq y\}$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb R^2}\mathbb P\{X_1\leq x-x_2, X_3\leq y-x_4\mid X_2=x_2, X_4=x_4\}\times $$
$$\mathbb P\{X_2\in \mathrm dx_2, X_4\in \mathrm dx_4\}.\tag{E}$$

Since $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independants, $$\mathbb P\{X_1\leq x-x_2,X_3\leq y-x_4\mid X_2=x_2,X_4=x_4\}=\mathbb P\{X_1\leq x-x_2\mid X_2=x_2,X_4=x_4\}\mathbb P\{X_3\leq y-x_4\mid X_2=x_2,X_4=x_4\},$$
and since $X_2$ and $X_4$ are independents $$\mathbb P\{X_2\in \mathrm dx_2,X_4\in \mathrm dx_4\}=\mathbb P\{X_2\in \mathrm d x_2\}\mathbb P\{X_4\in \mathrm d x_4\}.$$

Therefore, using the fact that $X_4$  is independant of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is independent of $X_3$,$$\mathbb P\{X_1\leq x-x_2\mid X_2=x_2,X_4=x_4\}=\mathbb P\{X_1\leq x-x_2\mid X_2=x_2\}$$ and $$\mathbb P\{X_3\leq x-x_4\mid X_2=x_2,X_4=x_4\}=\mathbb P\{X_3\leq x-x_4\mid X_4=x_4\}.$$  Finally, $(E)$ becomes
$$\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\{X_1\leq x-x_2\mid X_2=x_2\}\mathbb P\{X_2\in \mathrm d x_2\}\times\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\{X_3\leq y-x_4\mid X_4=x_4\}\mathbb P\{X_4\in \,\mathrm d x_4\}=\mathbb P\{X_1+X_2\leq x\}\mathbb P\{X_3+X_4\leq y\},$$
as wished.

---

Notice that we can prove it more nicely using class monotone theorem. But I wasn't sure if you knew it, so I show is brute force.

Comment: Could you please show me how to use monotone class theorem to prove it?

Comment: @Vector: See theorem 2.1.6 in the book of durrett : probability, theory and example (4th edition).

Comment: what is $\mathbb P\{X_2\in \mathrm dx_2, X_4\in \mathrm dx_4\}$?

Comment: it's the joint probability measure, i.e. $$\mathbb P\{X_2\in A,X_4\in B\}=\iint_{A\times B} \mathbb P\{X_2\in \mathrm d x_2,X_4\in \mathrm dx_4\}.$$ So, if $X_2$ and $X_4$ are continuous, $$\mathbb P\{X_2\in \mathrm d x_2,X_4\in \mathrm d x_4\}=f_{X_2,X_4}(x_2,x_4)\,\mathrm d x_2\,\mathrm d x_4,$$ where $f_{X_2,X_4}$ is the joint distribution. If they are discrete, then $\mathbb P\{X_2\in \,\mathrm d x_2,X_4\in \,\mathrm d x_4\}=\mathbb P\{X_2=x_2, X_4=x_4\}\delta _{(x_2,x_4)}(\mathrm dx_2\times\mathrm  dx_4)$ where $\delta _{(x_2,x_4)}$ is the dirac mass at $(x_2,x_4)$,

Comment: and if they are neither continuous nor discrete, then we usualy write $\mathbb P\{X_2\in dx_2,X_4\in dx_4\}$ for the joint probability measure. Since you didn't precise the nature of $X+Y$, I couldn't guess how they behave...@Vector

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses characteristic functions. We want to show$$\mathbb Ee^{is(X_1+X_2)+it(X_3+X_4)}=\mathbb Ee^{is(X_1+X_2)}\mathbb Ee^{it(X_3+X_4)}$$for all $s,\,t\in\Bbb R$. But this is the special case of the more general$$\Bbb Ee^{iwX_1+ixX_2+iyX_3+izX_4}=\Bbb E^{iwX_1}\Bbb E^{ixX_2}\Bbb E^{iyX_3}\Bbb E^{izX_4}$$with $w=x=s,\,y=z=t$.